# Why does the UISearchDisplayController sometimes work, sometimes not?

Tags: uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have an UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController implemented correctly to filter the cells in a UITableView.

Sometimes it works fine and filters the cells according to the entered search term.
But sometimes - without changing a line of code - it doesn't filter and shows all cells.

In the tableView delegates I notice that the `IF` statement below would be `FALSE` and thus display all contacts as search results in `searchResultsTableView`.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [_searchResultContacts count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [_allContacts count];
    }
}
```

Why is that?

(Don't answer, I will post the answer below!)

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that I accidentally added multiple UISearchDisplayControllers in the same view in story board.

Because of overlapping I did not notice it until I saw it in the document outline window of Xcode.

[image]

After removing all but one search display controller, it worked fine.
Make sure the outlet connections are properly set.

Took me some time to find out, so I hope this is of help to someone.